# Web animations and video not working on a old laptop

Tags: web, animation, video

I am currently working on a fully animated website. When I open it on my home desktop PC or on my phone, all the animations and videos work fine. However, when I open it on my laptop, none of these work on any of the browsers I have tried.

The laptop is equipped with an Intel Core i3-2328M and an integrated GPU (Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000). Do you have any solutions?

Thank you very much.